# How can I line up my html elements in an element?

Tags: html, css, line

I have a navigation bar with hyperlinks to other pages. I decided to use different divisions for each hyperlink because I couldn't get them to spread out. When I execute this on my browser, two of the hyperlinks(both the right ones) are slightly below the other ones. I don't know if that is because of my mac or if it's an error in the code. Could someone please tell me how I can make sure all hyperlinks are evenly lied up in 2 lines?

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 28pt;
  background-color: #F64C72;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 17pt;
}

.connectp1 {
  text-align: left;
}

.connectp2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.connectp3 {
  text-align: right;
}

.connectp4 {
  text-align: left;
}

.connectp5 {
  text-align: center;
}

.connectp6 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div>
    <div class="connectp1">
      <a href="cpage1.html">First Peoples </a>
    </div>
    <div class="connectp2">
      <a href="cpage2.html">Natives And Newcomers</a>
    </div>

    <div class="connectp3">
      <a href="cpage3.html">Provincial Centre</a>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="connectp4">
      <a href="cpage4.html">Industrializing City</a>
    </div>

    <div class="connectp5">
      <a href="cpage5.html">Wars And Crises</a>
    </div>

    <div class="connectp6">
      <a href="cpage6.html">The Modern Metropolis</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need extra layers to spread out. Inline elements like `<a>` are better for this kind of menus, so just keep it simple. The code bellow will split in two lines only if required.

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #F64C72;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
} 
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="menu">
      <a href="cpage1.html">First Peoples </a>
      <a href="cpage2.html">Natives And Newcomers</a>

      <a href="cpage3.html">Provincial Centre</a>
</div>
  <div class="menu">
      <a href="cpage4.html">Industrializing City</a>

      <a href="cpage5.html">Wars And Crises</a>

      <a href="cpage6.html">The Modern Metropolis</a>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

However I recommend you considering some improvements in your design to help the menu look more tidy.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a perfect opportunity to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) setting [`justify-content`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/). We can just work with a `div` to hold all the nav and then a `div` for each row then the links directly.

`flexbox` handles the distribution of the `a` elements in our instance, while setting `justify-content: space-between` determines how the `a` elements are spaced.

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 28pt;
  background-color: #F64C72;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 17pt;
}

.navbar > div  {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div>    
      <a href="cpage1.html">First Peoples </a>        
      <a href="cpage2.html">Natives And Newcomers</a>        
      <a href="cpage3.html">Provincial Centre</a>    
  </div>
  <div>    
      <a href="cpage4.html">Industrializing City</a>
      <a href="cpage5.html">Wars And Crises</a>    
      <a href="cpage6.html">The Modern Metropolis</a>    
  </div>
</div>
```

With IE 10 you will need to prefix with `-ms-` and it won't work at all with older versions of IE if you need to support IE 9 and earlier. See: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/

Comment: I agree with you Jon P, but maybe flexbox is too advanced for his level, don't you think?

Comment: While flexbox can get, shall we say, intricate, in  this instance it is fairly simple and doesn't get too involved with the trickier side of flexbox. Therefore I think it's the perfect introduction.

Answer (score 0):

You would be much better off using unordered lists `(ul)` with list items `(<li>)`, and then displaying the lists as table rows/table cells as in the snippet below, and vertically aligning to top. Btw, your current css includes duplication, there is no need to created 2 different classes to text-align to the right (e.g)

Feel free to adjust the snippet ( I reduced the huge font size! - so that the adjustments could be seen in the snippet)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav {
  margin: auto;
  top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 13pt;
  background-color: #F64C72;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: table-row;
}

ul li {
  display:table-cell;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;

}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="cpage1.html">First Peoples </a></li>
    <li><a href="cpage2.html">Natives And Newcomers</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="cpage3.html">Provincial Centre</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class=""><a href="cpage4.html">Industrializing City</a>
    </li>

    <li class="">
      <a href="cpage5.html">Wars And Crises</a>
    </li>

    <li class="">
      <a href="cpage6.html">The Modern Metropolis</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 semantic elements when possible. In your case, the `nav` element is the proper tool for the job. [MDN shows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav):

```css
nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.crumbs ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.crumb {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="crumbs">
    <ol>
        <li class="crumb"><a href="bikes">Acme</a></li>
        <li class="crumb"><a href="bikes/bmx">Foo</a></li>
        <li class="crumb"><a href="bikes/bar">Bar</a></li>
    </ol>
</nav>

<h1>Jump Bike 3000</h1>
<p>This BMX bike is a solid step into the pro world. It looks as legit as it rides and is built to polish your skills.</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

`<div>` elements are block-level elements, so take up `100%` of the `width` of a 'row' by default. While you can correct this by simply changing their `display` to `inline-block`, I would recommend replacing them with `<span>` tags instead (which are inline-block by default):

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 28pt;
  background-color: #F64C72;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 17pt;
}

.connectp1 {
  text-align: left;
}

.connectp2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.connectp3 {
  text-align: right;
}

.connectp4 {
  text-align: left;
}

.connectp5 {
  text-align: center;
}

.connectp6 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div>
    <span class="connectp1">
      <a href="cpage1.html">First Peoples </a>
    </span>
    <span class="connectp2">
      <a href="cpage2.html">Natives And Newcomers</a>
    </span>
    <span class="connectp3">
      <a href="cpage3.html">Provincial Centre</a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="connectp4">
      <a href="cpage4.html">Industrializing City</a>
    </span>
    <span class="connectp5">
      <a href="cpage5.html">Wars And Crises</a>
    </span>
    <span class="connectp6">
      <a href="cpage6.html">The Modern Metropolis</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you're also likely looking for `float: left` and `float: right`
 rather than `text-align: left` and `text-align: right`, in order to separate out your elements. There's no `float: center`, though this isn't needed. You can also combine your selectors in this regard to save space, as can be seen in the following:

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 28pt;
  background-color: #F64C72;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 17pt;
}

.connectp1, .connectp4 {
  float: left;
}

.connectp3, .connectp6  {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div>
    <span class="connectp1">
      <a href="cpage1.html">First Peoples </a>
    </span>
    <span class="connectp2">
      <a href="cpage2.html">Natives And Newcomers</a>
    </span>
    <span class="connectp3">
      <a href="cpage3.html">Provincial Centre</a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="connectp4">
      <a href="cpage4.html">Industrializing City</a>
    </span>
    <span class="connectp5">
      <a href="cpage5.html">Wars And Crises</a>
    </span>
    <span class="connectp6">
      <a href="cpage6.html">The Modern Metropolis</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not my downvote but one nitpick. `span` is `inline` by default, not `inline-block`.